# Visual Studio 2013 Changes access modifiers when editing form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Anyone having any issues with Visual Studio 2013 (VS) changing a Windows Form object's access modifier when editing a windows form.

The language is VB, and when ever the windows form is edited via the form designer, VS will change the objects' members access modifiers from protected to friend, which then causes the code to not compile due to access level issues.  This then means that it will not compile until I change them back to what they were before.

Has anyone else had this issue, and is there something can be done to stop this from happening all the time?

Cheers in advance.  :)

Comment: The designer code belongs to the Designer.  If you looks there is a warning: *...Do not modify it using the code editor.*

Comment: From the VB Documentation:  "You can use Protected only at class level, and only when you declare a member of a class. This means you can declare a protected element in a class, but not at the level of a source file or namespace, or inside an interface, module, structure, or procedure."  You are trying to do something not allowed by the language.

Comment: @TnTinMn since a form *is* a class, it is perfectly legal - its just that it is not his code to modify.

Comment: @Plutonix, yes a  Form is a class and it may be declared Protected if it is child of another Class.  For it to be editable via the designer, it must be declared at the project's root Namespace level (at least as far as I know) and doing so is not a use at the Class level.

Comment: After re-reading the question, I think that I misunderstood the OP's problem.  I now believe that he is not trying to make the Form Protected, but rather changing the access modifiers of the Form's child control's via the property grid.  If that is the case, then something strange is going on if they are reverting to the default Friend access level.

Comment: They are reverting because the form designer will rewrite the designer code when the form changes.  perfectly normal. @TnTinMn

Comment: @Plutonix - What I am referring to is the "Modifier" property exposed via the PropertyGrid.  Unrequested reversion of values set in the designer to default values is definitely not normal. In the case of "'Modifier" on a control, the true default is Private, but VB overrides that when the control is placed on the design surface.

Comment: Sorry everybody, but I think everybody has completely missed my question .   I completely understand what access modifiers are and how they are used and that the designer builds the code for me.   What has started happening is that the designer is writing everything as friend, which will not compile.   In other words, it is the designer auto-generation of code that is causing the problem.   I can fix it, it's just annoying that I have to do so every time i edit the form.... I might as well not use VS and type in the code myself.

Comment: @GuyPark, Is this only happening on a single project or even new projects?  How long has the behavior been happening?  It is not normal, and it is possible that your VS install has become corrupted.  I'm also having a trouble visualizing how an Access of Friend vs Protected on Form components is prohibiting code from functioning unless you are inheriting from this Form.

Comment: It's only been happening in the last 2 weeks.  The form has been around for years and never been a problem until around 2 weeks ago it just started doing it.   Might try a reinstall of VS and see if that sorts it, was just hoping someone may have experienced this same issue and it was just a simple "delete this temporary cache file from X".  :)